# Adding TableRows dynamically in Android doesn't work

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I got a little problem with adding tablerows to a table layout in android.

Here's my code:

```
int z = 0;
        for(String detail: details){
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            //odd / even
            if(z%2 == 0)
                tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F5F5F5"));

            //set detail text
            TextView detailText = new TextView(this);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams dtlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);        
            detailText.setTextSize(16.0f);
            detailText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
            detailText.setPadding(20, 10, 20, 10);
            detailText.setLayoutParams(dtlp);
            detailText.setText(detail);
            tr.addView(detailText);

            detailsTable.addView(tr);

            ++z;
        }
```

I cannot figure out where the problem is. The detail textview is being set but the tablerows won't show up.

Comment: every thing is ok with the code above, you have to work with LayoutParams, also try this **detailsTable.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(...,....))**

Comment: Check **TableLayout** height and width in your **YOUR_LAYOUT.xml**, since you have set **TableRow width to MATCH_PARENT** change it to WRAP_CONTENT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a. Try changing dtlp's "**width parameter**" to "**RelativeLayout.MATCH_PARENT**"

**OR**

b. Before For loop block create two layout params like this.

```
TableLayout.LayoutParams tlps=new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

TableRow.LayoutParams trps=new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

**In loop Replace**

```
  detailText.setLayoutParams(dtlp);
```

**WITH**

```
  detailText.setLayoutParams(trps);
```

**And  replace**

```
   detailsTable.addView(tr);
```

**with**

```
    detailsTable.addView(tr,tlps);
```

hope this helps.